# Virtual IP, and Reverse Proxying Ports (Making up terms)

Tags: networking, vpn, minecraft

So here is the exact situation that I have

- I have 2 game servers in my house. One on port 25565, and the second on 25567. I have only one IP in my house
- I need to get a "virtual IP" for the second server. Some way of giving the computer that runs these game servers a second IP (linux)
- I need the Virtual IP to receive connections on 25565 and forward the data to 25567. Although if linux recognizes the second IP in networking I assume I can bind to the second IP on port 25565

Comment: So the game client is hardcoded to use a single port to contact the server?  That's unfortunate. You won't be able to do this unless you have 2 or more public IPs. If you do, it's a simple matter of NAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I purchased a VPS

Then installed this package named "Simpleproxy"

Then ran the following command

```
simpleproxy -L 25565 -R mc.xyzcraft.net:25567
```

It proxies the TCP Connection on port 25565 to another address "mc.xyzcraft.net:25567"

Comment: Interesting and useful solution. I presume you checked the terms of service to make sure they were happy with you running an proxy? Many VPS providers explicitly deny proxies.

Comment: Just Ran into that problem. I'm purchasing a higher level VPS from them as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you actually want is to access the two minecraft servers from outside your home?

As you probably know, you can set any port you like for a minecraft server simply by changing the config so that isn't a problem.

In fact, I can't see any problem here at all? You do need to make sure that your Internet router allows inbound traffic on both ports and to tell people that you want to allow to connect what port to use. But that's it, you don't in fact need two IP addresses.

When users wish to connect to your servers, they select Multiplayer, Add Server (or Direct Connect). Then in the URL box, they enter the IP Address with a port like so:

```
111.222.333.444:25567
```

Which will connect to the second Minecraft server assuming that the port is configured for inbound traffic both on the router AND on the Linux box (if you cannot access the server internally, temporarily disable the IPTABLES firewall on the Linux box).

Comment: I understand this, I want to remove the port number from the equation because it looks tacky and unprofessional.

Comment: Ah, you mean it looks like Minecraft! ;)